# How to make a link that opens a specific app in the android app market app

Tags: android

I am trying to promote my app on Facebook, but when I link to the application page [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isotope.Button_Wars), when the link is opened on an android device the page comes up in the browser, instead of opening in the Play Store app.  How can I create a link that when opened in a web browser on a PC will link to the previously linked page, but when opened on a phone will open in the Play Store app?

Comment: Pleas explain it in more detail as to what you require

Comment: @Rahul I am trying to make a link (which would be posted to Facebook or another social media site) so that if someone is viewing the link on a smartphone, when clicked it opens the market app on my apps page

Comment: Open your app page in the market. Copy the address and spread it. Simple

Comment: The issue is that the facebook app for android, when exceuting links, goes to the m.facebook.com site and then launches the link.  The user never gets the dialog to launch the play app.  As far as I can tell the best way to go would be to just host the link somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Android app you can use:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

From a website:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

More information on [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).